# Design suggestion: How to add programmatically add multiple (but indeterminate) 'Views' of the same class in an Android Activity

Tags: android

I have this problem that I am not able to solve.

An Activity in my Android app needs to build an object that has:

- a name
- a description
- zero or more items, described by name, price, and other info

I have tried to implement the functionalities related to 'items' in a `Fragment`. Using a `Fragment` made sense to me because I would have been able to add some logic (various checks on the values) in the Fragment and have a lighter activity. I built my Activity with

- EditText for name
- EditText for description
- an ImageView '+' for adding Fragments
- a `LinearLayout` hosting the added fragments

I cannot use `Fragments` because they are not kept during device rotation (I tried to restore the same views in the LinearLayout, with the same ids, but it does not work).

How could I implement such a functionality? I could not find any example.

Comment: You can keep fragments in rotation by turning off rotation in the manifest.  Or you can keep track of what fragments need to be restored and readd them in onRestoreInstanceState.

Comment: I try to keep track of the fragments, but I am not able to restore their views when the device rotates: after the rotation the fragments are still alive, but without views.

Comment: That's because the activity is killed and restarted around rotation.  You'd have to implement onSaveInstanceState and onRestoreInstanceState to remember them.  Or just turn off rotations killing activities.

Comment: I implemented both onSaveInstanceState and onRestoreInstanceState, I tried several implementations but Fragments are not restored. I add the fragments to a LinearLayout and when I rotate the device some of them disappears. The only solution I found is to destroy the fragments on rotation, create new ones, and restore their internal state. However, there should be a simpler solution. There is no point in disabling rotations: first, it need to work with rotations, second they are a way to test activity restart.